# Auto-size and drag items into panel

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

I want to implement panel where items are placed using the following layout:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { Box, Grid, Tab, Tabs, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { sizing } from "@material-ui/system";

const useStyles1 = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    color: {
        backgroundColor: "green",
        border: "1px solid black"
    }
}));

const useStyles2 = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    color: {
        backgroundColor: "mediumvioletred",
        border: "1px solid black"
    }
}));

const useStyles3 = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    color: {
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        border: "1px solid black"
    }
}));

export default function Hello() {
    const classes1 = useStyles1();
    const classes2 = useStyles2();
    const classes3 = useStyles3();

    return (
        <>
            <Grid
                spacing={0}
                container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="flex-start"
                xs={12}
                alignItems={"stretch"}
                style={{ height: "100vh", overflow: "auto", flexGrow: 1 }}
            >
                <Grid
                    // spacing={0}
                    // container
                    // direction="row"
                    // xs={3}
                    //  style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}
                >
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Grid
                            className={classes1.color}
                            container
                            direction="column"
                            justifyContent="flex-start"
                            alignItems="center"
                        >
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Box m={2}>item link 1</Box>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Box m={2}>item link 2</Box>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Box m={2}>item link 3</Box>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Box m={2}>item link 4</Box>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <Grid
                    spacing={0}
                    container
                    direction="row"
                    xs={2}
                    className={classes2.color}
                    style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}
                >
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box m={10}>item 11</Box>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box m={10}>item 11</Box>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box m={10}>item 13</Box>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box m={10}>item 14</Box>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box m={10}>item 15</Box>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box m={10}>item 16</Box>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                    container
                    direction="row"
                    xs={4}
                    alignItems={"stretch"}
                    style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}
                >
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Grid
                            className={classes3.color}
                            container
                            direction="row"
                            justifyContent="space-around"
                            alignItems="center"
                            style={{ width: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}
                        >
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Box m={2}>item area 1</Box>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Box m={2}>item area 2</Box>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </>
    );
}
```

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-k6hpuf?file=Hello.tsx

Do you know how I can implement drag for the borders and proper layout using typescript?

Comment: `stackbiltz` link which you have attached doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is a issue which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "...how I can implement drag for the folders..." ? From your diagram, I don't see any mention of "folders." Only "borders." Is the question how to implement horizontally-draggable dividers between panels? Or are you asking about dragging and dropping folders or items or something?

Comment: Also, just curious... is MaterialUI a required dependency for your project? Or were you just using it to try to solve your immediate problem?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to drag the borders. I started the project with Material UI. It will be best if I have this screen using Material.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In addition to dragging borders between panels, does the UX also require dragging and dropping items from one panel to another? If so, can you be more specific about the desired UX? As-is, each column has a list of elements that each contain the word "item" which is a bit confusing. If dragging and dropping is a requirement, it would be very helpful to know "what" needs to be dragged and dropped "where" and "how" that should behave. Thanks! :)

Comment: "dragging and dropping items from one panel to another" - no, but I would like to change order of the items into second and third column using dragging.

Comment: Ok, so items in the purple and and orange columns should be manually sortable via drag. But green column on the left is static. Is that correct? One more question... I understand that your app requires a Material UI integration, but is it essential that the Material `<Grid>` component be used for the high-level layout, or would you accept a custom container component for the resizable panels?

Comment: "items in the purple and and orange columns should be manually sortable via drag" - yes. "But green column on the left is static" - yes. If possible let's implement it using Material. If not let's use custom. For future maintenance I prefer using Material.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Are you open to using additional React/TypeScript libraries for drag/sort UX? Or do you require that Material be the only external library?

Comment: If possible let's implement it using Material. If not I'm also open to additional React libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-drag-and-drop-so-example-finished-state-with-propper-spacing-8okx1) using Material UI and `react-beautiful-dnd`

Using drag and drop based on a ticket-based system like Jira

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { DragDropContext } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import Column from "./Column";

const App = () => {
  function range(start, end) {
    return Array(end - start + 1)
      .fill()
      .map((_, idx) => start + idx);
  }

  const initialColumns = {
    links: {
      id: "links",
      list: [
        { id: "1", text: "text1" },
        { id: "2", text: "text2" },
        { id: "3", text: "text3" }
      ]
    },
    items: {
      id: "items",
      list: []
    },
    area1: {
      id: "area1",
      list: []
    },
    area2: {
      id: "area2",
      list: [
        { id: "7", text: "text7" },
        { id: "8", text: "text8" },
        { id: "9", text: "text9" }
      ]
    }
  };

  range(4, 25).forEach((idx) => {
    initialColumns.area1.list.push({
      id: idx.toString(),
      text: "text" + idx.toString()
    });
  });

  range(24, 60).forEach((idx) => {
    initialColumns.items.list.push({
      id: idx.toString(),
      text: "text" + idx.toString()
    });
  });

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(initialColumns);

  const onDragEnd = ({ source, destination }) => {
    // Make sure we have a valid destination
    if (destination === undefined || destination === null) return null;

    // Make sure we're actually moving the item
    if (
      source.droppableId === destination.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    )
      return null;

    // Set start and end variables
    const start = columns[source.droppableId];
    const end = columns[destination.droppableId];

    // If start is the same as end, we're in the same column
    if (start === end) {
      // Move the item within the list
      // Start by making a new list without the dragged item
      console.log(start);
      const newList = start.list.filter((_, idx) => idx !== source.index);

      // Then insert the item at the right location
      newList.splice(destination.index, 0, start.list[source.index]);

      // Then create a new copy of the column object
      const newCol = {
        id: start.id,
        list: newList
      };

      // Update the state
      setColumns((state) => ({ ...state, [newCol.id]: newCol }));
      return null;
    } else {
      // If start is different from end, we need to update multiple columns
      // Filter the start list like before
      const newStartList = start.list.filter((_, idx) => idx !== source.index);

      // Create a new start column
      const newStartCol = {
        id: start.id,
        list: newStartList
      };

      // Make a new end list array
      const newEndList = end.list;

      // Insert the item into the end list
      newEndList.splice(destination.index, 0, start.list[source.index]);

      // Create a new end column
      const newEndCol = {
        id: end.id,
        list: newEndList
      };

      // Update the state
      setColumns((state) => ({
        ...state,
        [newStartCol.id]: newStartCol,
        [newEndCol.id]: newEndCol
      }));
      return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="space-around"
        alignItems="stretch"
      >
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <Column
            isLinks={true}
            backgroundColor={"lightgreen"}
            height={"90vh"}
            width={"100%"}
            column={columns.links}
            key={columns.links.id}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <Column
            backgroundColor={"salmon"}
            height={"90vh"}
            width={"100%"}
            column={columns.items}
            key={columns.items.id}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          <Column
            className={"flex-col-scroll"}
            height={"42vh"}
            width={"100%"}
            backgroundColor={"darkorange"}
            column={columns.area1}
            key={columns.area1.id}
          />
          <Column
            className={"flex-col-scroll"}
            height={"42vh"}
            width={"100%"}
            backgroundColor={"darkorange"}
            column={columns.area2}
            key={columns.area2.id}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
};

export default App;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({}));
```

Column.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import RootRef from "@material-ui/core/RootRef";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItemCustom from "./ListItemCustom";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const Column = ({ isLinks, height, width, backgroundColor, column }) => {
  const linksStyle = !isLinks
    ? {
        maxHeight: "85%",
        overflow: "auto"
      }
    : {};

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: height,
        width: width,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        margin: 10,
        padding: 20,
        color: "white"
      }}
    >
      <Typography variant={"h4"}>{column.id}</Typography>
      <Droppable droppableId={column.id}>
        {(provided) => (
          <RootRef rootRef={provided.innerRef}>
            <List style={linksStyle}>
              {column.list.map((itemObject, index) => {
                return <ListItemCustom index={index} itemObject={itemObject} />;
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </List>
          </RootRef>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Column;
```

ListItemCustom.js

```
import React from "react";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import ListItemSecondaryAction from "@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const ListItemCustom = ({ itemObject, index }) => {
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={itemObject.id} key={itemObject.id} index={index}>
      {(provided) => (
        <ListItem
          key={itemObject.id}
          role={undefined}
          dense
          button
          ContainerComponent="li"
          ContainerProps={{ ref: provided.innerRef }}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        >
          <ListItemText
            sytles={{ fontFamily: "Quicksand" }}
            primary={`${itemObject.text}`}
          />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            <IconButton
              edge="end"
              aria-label="comments"
              question-uid={itemObject.id}
            >
              {/* <DeleteIcon /> */}
            </IconButton>
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  );
};

export default ListItemCustom;
```

Update 1: added bad scrolling

Update 2: added scrolling and another vertical sidebar like in the architecture

Update 3: reordered layout spacing using material UI grid API

Update 4: added main Code in case code sandbox link breaks

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to add auto-resize to fit the screen and vertical scroll?

Comment: Here try now, I've made the requested changes

Comment: Please try to include all the relevant code/explanation in the answer itself. Otherwise if at some point that link breaks then the answer becomes meaningless to any future readers.

Comment: Can you also add first column according to the layout's picture and vertical scrollbars for the second and third areas, please?

Comment: PeterPenzov made requested changes, @DBS will add necessary code soon thanks for the feedback on improving my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you! I added some comments: https://ibb.co/XCF9YVX

Comment: scrolling is implemented and be visible if more items will be added (that's regarding every bracket), now with the single scroll bar - I didn't understand its purpose to have a single scroll bar but two separate areas? anyway, because the main issue was resolved I think a separate question is in order

Comment: ok, last thing. Can you implement a listener which opens items into the next items, please? The idea is this: I want to click on a link(first panel) and load a list of items into the second panel. Them when I click on a item I want to load a item into the third panel.

Comment: "third panel" being one of the two areas the user will choose to move the draggable object to?

Comment: The idea is that the orange area is like the other two areas but with bigger items and autofits the remaining screen area.

Comment: Tried for some time now and it looks like it would require a serious refactor on my part. Maybe a paid job is a better solution for such custom modifications.

Comment: ok, thank you for the effort. If it's possible please return back the code till the working solution of you don't have time left?

Comment: reverted and improved spacing between brackets using Material UI props API

Comment: Thank you! One last request. Can you implement the solution using Typescript please?

Comment: Not a master to presume I can with confidence convert this to using typescript I'm afraid, sorry ☹️